# Selecting last record in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hello I need to select last record in a table(bill_account_billcycle). After finding it I need to take bill_date column date from last record and need implement inside my cursors' query.
I read rownum max etc but couldnt succeed to implement. I am open to advices. I am going to add a screenshoot of one bill_account record to there and my scripts. thank you from now.

[image]

```
    CURSOR c1 IS
SELECT DISTINCT intl_prod_id
      FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
           acct_bill ab,
           bill_acct_billcycle bab
      WHERE abr.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
          AND abr.TAX_CATG_ID = 'NOTAX'
          AND abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id
          AND ab.bill_date = bab.bill_date IN (select );-- I should do something here.
```

Comment: There is no concept of "last" (or "first") without an ORDER BY.

Comment: @EdStevens so how world citizens handle that issue?

Comment: _"so how world citizens handle that issue"_  Well, I don't know what citizenship has to do with it, but _developers_ would handle it by providing the appropriate [ORDER BY clause.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Sorting-Query-Results.html#GUID-E45EF993-20AC-4552-860C-4D74EADB5BF2)

Comment: @EdStevens Hallelujah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like

```
CURSOR c1 IS
SELECT DISTINCT intl_prod_id
  FROM apld_bill_rt abr
       JOIN acct_bill ab ON abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id
 WHERE     ab.bill_date = (SELECT MAX (bab.bill_date)
                             FROM bill_account_billcycle bab)
       --
       AND abr.chrg_tp = 'INSTALLMENT'
       AND abr.tax_catg_id = 'NOTAX'
```

i.e. remove `bill_account_billcycle` table from cursor's `FROM` clause; select the *last* date using a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12, you can use `ORDER BY` and then `FETCH FIRST`:

```sql
CURSOR c1 IS
  SELECT DISTINCT
         intl_prod_id
  FROM   apld_bill_rt abr
         INNER JOIN acct_bill ab
         ON (abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id)
         INNER JOIN bill_acct_billcycle bab
         ON (ab.bill_date = bab.bill_date)
  WHERE  abr.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
  ORDER BY bab.bill_date DESC
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

If you want multiple rows with the latest date than use `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES`.